# How to retrieve response headers from CONNECT request using apache java HttpClient 4.5?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

i use an http proxy to connect on an https website through CloseableHttpClient. A CONNECT request is sent first because it must do a tunnel connection. There will be response headers sent and i need to retrieve them. Result will be stored in a variable and used later.

On HttpClient 4.2, i can achieve it using an HttpResponseInterceptor :

```java
final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
//configure proxy


httpclient.addResponseInterceptor(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {
    public void process(HttpResponse httpResponse, HttpContext httpContext) throws HttpException, IOException {
        final Header[] headers = httpResponse.getAllHeaders();

        //store headers
    }
});
```

But when i use HttpClient 4.5, my response interceptor is never called on CONNECT request. It jumps directly on GET or POST request :

```java
 final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort, "http"))
                .addInterceptorFirst(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {
                    public void process(HttpResponse httpResponse, HttpContext httpContext) throws HttpException, IOException {
                        final Header[] headers = httpResponse.getAllHeaders();

                        //store headers
                    }
                }).build();
```

Same result for methods `setInterceptorLast()` and `setHttpProcessor()`.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need a custom `HttpClientBuilder` class in order to be able to add custom protocol interceptor to the HTTP protocol processor used to execute `CONNECT` methods.

**HttpClient 4.5**
It is not pretty but it will get the job done:

```
HttpClientBuilder builder = new HttpClientBuilder() {

    @Override
    protected ClientExecChain createMainExec(
            HttpRequestExecutor requestExec,
            HttpClientConnectionManager connManager,
            ConnectionReuseStrategy reuseStrategy,
            ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy keepAliveStrategy,
            HttpProcessor proxyHttpProcessor,
            AuthenticationStrategy targetAuthStrategy,
            AuthenticationStrategy proxyAuthStrategy,
            UserTokenHandler userTokenHandler) {

        final ImmutableHttpProcessor myProxyHttpProcessor = new ImmutableHttpProcessor(
                Arrays.asList(new RequestTargetHost()),
                Arrays.asList(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {

                    @Override
                    public void process(
                            HttpResponse response,
                            HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {

                    }
                })
        );

        return super.createMainExec(requestExec, connManager, reuseStrategy, keepAliveStrategy,
                myProxyHttpProcessor, targetAuthStrategy, proxyAuthStrategy, userTokenHandler);
    }

};
```

**HttpClient 5.0 classic**:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .replaceExecInterceptor(ChainElement.CONNECT.name(),
                new ConnectExec(
                        DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy.INSTANCE,
                        new DefaultHttpProcessor(new RequestTargetHost()),
                        DefaultAuthenticationStrategy.INSTANCE))
        .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @ok2c :) Unfortunately, issue persists for HttpClient 4.5. However, i have tested with HttpClient 5.0 and it runs as expected. I just added my response interceptor on the new DefaultHttpProcessor.

Comment: @RAZAFINARIVOHanania What exactly persists with HttpClient 4.5? It is the same principle, just a bit uglier implementation.

Comment: i can't intercept CONNECT response with HttpClient 4.5 using the custom HttpClientBuilder. However, it intercepts the CONNECT request. But on HttpClient 5 using your solution it runs, the `process()` function is called on response.

Comment: I check what does the `createMainExec()` do. I see that it creates new instance of `MainClientExec`. I discovery in this class that HttpProcessor is used one time only and only on request.

There is line `this.requestExecutor.preProcess(connect, this.proxyHttpProcessor, context);` But when it got response, there is no use of proxyHttpProcessor. I think it is the issue.